# How to pass a POJO to mybatis which was bound to a REST route

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am using declaring some REST routes, one of which is as below:

```
<put id="rest:award.linkfaq" uri="/award/faq" produces="application/json"
        consumes="application/json" type="com.foo.bar.FaqLink">
```

`FaqLink` is just a POJO with getter and setters for `id`, `awardId` and so on. I am also subsequently routing to a mybatis query as so:

```
<to uri="mybatis:linkFaq?statementType=SelectList&amp;inputHeader=${in.body}"
id="linkFaq.mybatis:linkFaq" />
```

In the SqlMapper, even though I have declared the `ParamType` as `FaqLink` (after declaration as a `TypeAlias`), the variables used as part of the query such as `#{id}`, `#{awardId}`still resolve to null.

What am I doing incorrectly that I am unable to get the SqlMapper to get the variables from the said POJO? I logged `${in.body}` and it seems to be an instance of `FaqLink`

Comment: Why do you have specified `inputHeader` then? The parameters are mapped from body by default. `"inputHeader" parameter to use a header value as input to the component instead of the body.`, [See](http://camel.apache.org/mybatis.html)

Comment: I guess you are right, let me try that out, @Bedla. TY.